# Starbase connection to Hbase

Tags: configuration, connection, hbase

I want to use starbase to connect to Hbase on a different machine. How should my HBase configuration look like?

On the remote machine, HBase is installed in `/opt/somedir/hbase/`. It has a `conf` folder which has the following files.

```
>> ls
hadoop-metrics.properties  hbase-env.sh      hbase-site.xml    regionservers
hbase-env.cmd              hbase-policy.xml  log4j.properties
```

`hbase-site.xml` does not have any port information except for `zookeeper` port, which I believe is not the remote server port for HBase.

From my client machine, I did the following.

```
>>python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from starbase import Connection
>>> c = Connection(host='hbase-machine-ip',port=60010)
>>> c.tables()
[]
```

I used port 60010 because the documentation said that this was the port for HBase-GUI.

I have the following questions.

1. Is my HBase configured to accept remote connections? On what port? If not, how can I specify this setting?
2. How do I specify the user/password information in connection? My client machine username is 'nik' whereas the HBase machine username is 'nik2'. My HBase tables are created in `/user/nik2/tables`. Please let me know how I should specify my connection.
3. There are 3 tables in HBase, yet `c.tables()` shows an empty list. So either the connection is not correct, or I am not correctly specifying the path to tables. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starbase does not connect directly to HBase it connects to [Stargate](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate) - HBase REST API ([see the documentation page for starbase](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/starbase)). You need to see that stargate is installed and running. The port you would use is the Starbase port